# UIImageView inArray property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How would I go about adding some kind of *inarray* property to an imageview, so when referring to that imageview I can read what array it's in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest approach is probably subclassing UIImageView:

```
@interface TrackedImageView : UIImageView {
    NSArray* parentArray;
}
@property(atomic,retain) NSArray* inarray;

@end

@implementation TrackedImageView

@synthesize inarray;

@end
```

Comment: That's how I pictured doing it... I just didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks man!